# JSON not showing image from this

Tags: php, json

my code wont show the screenshot header('Content-Type:image/png');

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/';
//API Url
$url2 = 'http://api.site:port/screenshot';

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url2);

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
    'url' => $url
);

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('content-type: application/json'));

//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

i have tested on postman this shows correct just not on php/json any ideas?

Comment: I'm not really following your question, did you want to output the image?

Comment: its supposed to do this https://gyazo.com/2bb17d70ec1ea790898e9c1e867fe8c9 @DE_

Comment: So the result from the API returns an image url or data, and you want to output that in the browser?

Comment: @DE_ its outputs a actual image and should just echo it basically but it returns nothing

Comment: Can you var_dump($result) so we can see what it's returning.

Comment: @DE_ here is the link to the code running http://crazyapi.tk/troubleshoot.php

Comment: Please share more details by editing your question. Why should it show any screenshot?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not going to help. how are you trying to output the image? Or could you tell us what API you are using?

Comment: im using a post api that outputs a screenshot of the url given @DE_

Comment: Sorry, but as Nico said, you're not giving us enough information to help you.

Comment: @DE_ what info do you want?

Comment: var_dump($result) returns bool(false) @NicoHaase

Comment: And ewhat do you **expect**?

Comment: @NicoHaase the image its just supposed to respond with the picture